# Php str_replace limit in Array

Tags: limit, str-replace

```
$orjinal =$_POST['orjinal'];

$false = file_get_contents("false.txt");
$true = file_get_contents("true.txt");
$false1 = explode("\n", $false);
$true1 = explode("\n", $true);
$new = str_replace($false1, $true1, $orjinal);
```

Working but changes two times the same words

```
false.txt"
apple
melon

true.txt
melon
strawberry

$orjinal="i am eating apple"
```

i want this output; "i am eating melon"
output ; "i am eating strawberry"

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Fix your false.txt and true.txt:

false.txt:

```
apple
```

true.txt:

```
melon
```

2. Call `str_replace()` twice (or as often as needed):

```
$new = str_replace($false1, $true1, $orjinal);
$new = str_replace($false1, $true1, $new);
```

3. Sit back and think once more about what exactly you want to achieve and if the simple `str_replace()` works exactly the way you intended or not.

Comment: 1-  i'cant delete lines, real code more specific  2-magnifying the problem 3- maybe but I believe there is a way